# Время работы процесса в системе

Tags: c#, windows-10

Как можно вывести время завершения процесса в системе, если после того, как мы его убили данные о нём стираются?

```
 DateTime startTime = process.StartTime;
    TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now - startTime;
Console.WriteLine("Наименование: {0}", process.ProcessName);
Console.WriteLine("Время запуска: {0}", startTime);
    if (process.HasExited) 
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Время завершения: {0}", process.ExitTime);
    }
Console.WriteLine("Длительность: {0}", duration.TotalSeconds + " секунд");
```

Comment: Сохранить значение перед убийстом)

Comment: Чей процесс? Кем он запускается? Я не думаю, что Windows хранит в себе эту информацию, а значит вам надо ее хранить самостоятельно. Например, если процессов много, вам нужно постоянно мониторить их, то подпишитесь на событие запуска/завершения процесса винды и высчитывайте время. Правда этот вариант подходит почти под все случаи)